# I want to put Margin Bottom for ConstraintLayout in kotlin, But when I do it, he ignores it

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

I want to put Margin Bottom for ConstraintLayout in kotlin

```
val params = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT) as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
params.height = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT
params.bottomMargin = 300
b.timerscreen.layoutParams = params
```

But when I do it, he ignores it.

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/keyboard"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

They are written in the markup initially.

Maybe this data can be registered in the code?

Comment: have you already defined constraints in xml ? if yes then please share the xml code .

Comment: Is your problem that the view ignores margin or that it ignores constraints set in xml?

Comment: @KamalNayan
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/timerscreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/phone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/keyboard"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

Comment: @SergeiKozelko view ignores margins and constrains set